# VSCode .hasOwnProperty() is not shown in IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

VSCode does not show `hasOwnProperty()` in IntelliSense.

According to this issue on GitHub this is intended. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54944

Is there a way to enable these common methods to be shown? (In JavaScript not TypeScript)

Answer (score 0):

`hasOwnProperty` is inside the `Object` prototype.

Almost all the objects inherit the `Object` prototype, but not all, for example:

```
const x = Object.create(null);
x.hasOwnProperty // undefined
```

If your object is defined as `any`, VS Code will predict that the object **could** not inherit from `Object`, so it won't show the suggestion since it's not considered safe.

If you want a better prediction, define the object as `Object` and not as `any`:

```
const x: Object;
```

If, instead, you have already defined the type, make sure it extends Object:

```
export interface Foo extends Object {
```

Comment: I don't use typescript. And if i create an object with `const test = {}` shouldn't it recognize based on the flow that this is indeed an object?

Answer (score 0):

If you use typescript you can try type casting?

[image]

Or

[image]

Comment: I don't use TypeScript